# JavaScript variable doesn't loop through Django model

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Topic is a CharField, summary is TextField within topic.

For some reason, the JavaScript doesn't loop through summary TextField -- it just uses the very first summary TextField and simply ignores the rest.

I want every summary TextField to looped through and displayed. Not just the first one.

Does this make sense? Something is wrong with my JavaScript code.

As you can see in the image -- second topic's (Bitcoin) summary is missing (highlighted in red) [Image displaying the problem on the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyrMY.png)

```
    {%for topic in topics%}

  
            <script>
                var i = 0;
               var txt = '{{topic.summary}}';
           
                   function typeWriter() {
                   if (i < txt.length) {
                       document.getElementsByClassName('js-typewrite')[0].innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
                       i++;
                       setTimeout(typeWriter, 65);
                   }
                   }
           
                   setTimeout(typeWriter, 1000);
               </script>
       
           
           <body>
           
               <p class="content">
                   <span class="typewrite anim-typewrite js-typewrite"></span>
               </p>
           
           </body>
   
        </div>
    





        <div id = 'mpost-text'>
            {{topic.text|linebreaks}}
        </div>

    

        <div id = 'change-text'> 
        {%if topic.owner == request.user and user.is_authenticated %}
            <a href = "{%url 'new_sites:post_edit' topic.id%}">Edit entry</a>
            <a href = "{%url 'new_sites:delete_post' topic.id%}">Delete topic</a>
         {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>

    

 


    {%empty%} 
        <li>No topics have been added yet.</li>
    {% endfor %}



{%if user.is_authenticated%}
    <a href="{% url 'new_sites:new_post'%}">Add Post</a>
{%endif%}
```

{%endblock%}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping everything, including the `<script>`, why not just loop the text and let javascript take care of the rest ?

```
{% for topic in topics %}
<p class="content">
  <span class="typewrite anim-typewrite js-typewrite">{{ topic.summary }}</span>
</p>
{% endfor %}

<script>
document.querySelectorAll('.js-typewrite').each(function() {
  // Do the typewriting animation here
})
</script>
```

Perhaps, unrelated to this problem, you should only have one `body` tag inside your HTML.
It's the body of the whole document, it doesn't mean body of an article.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am having issues with the JavaScript animation. I can't write a proper script to do the type writing effect -- I have very little experience with JavaScript. Currently the blinker works -- but the typing animation doesn't work at all. Any help would be appreciated.